# Hide content when tab is checked

Tags: html, css, sass

I have little tabs created using radio buttons, I trying when click to second tab (SPECIFICATION) to hide div with id "hide-me". To solve this problem I tried this:

```
ul.tabs [id^="#tab2"]:checked ~ #hide-me{
  display:none;
}
```

but not working.

How can I do this using only HTML5, CSS3 and SASS.

JSFIDDLE:

https://jsfiddle.net/2ucnpwbb/2/

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Lato;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ddd;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 0 100px 10px;
}
h1 span {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 4px;
}
.tabs {
  width: 650px;
  float: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px 0 0 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
.tabs li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
.tabs input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
.tabs label {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 21px;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #8e44ad;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.tabs label:hover {
  background: #703688;
}
.tabs .tab-content {
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53px;
  left: 0;
  background: #612e76;
}
.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked + label {
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 17px;
  background: #612e76;
}
.tabs [id^="tab"]:checked ~ [id^="tab-content"] {
  display: block;
}
p.link {
  clear: both;
  margin: 380px 0 0 15px;
}
p.link a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: #612e76;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
p.link a:hover {
  background-color: #522764;
}
#hide-me {
  margin-top: 250px;
  color: #000;
}
ul.tabs [id^="#tab2"]:checked ~ #hide-me {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tabs">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
    <label for="tab1">Description</label>
    <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
    <label for="tab2">Specification</label>
    <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
      <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
        voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius
        modi tempora incidunt</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div style="clear:both;">
</div>

<div id="hide-me">
  HIDE ME HIDE ME HIDE ME
</div>
```

Comment: The way you have your layout, you would have to traverse up through the objects parents in your css to get to the hide-me object.  As far as I know there are no parent selectors in CSS at this point, although I think it's part of the working spec.  You'd be much better off using javascript to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like that but its quite a hastle with the targeting ^^

code changed:

```
#tab1:checked + ul li:first-of-type label,
#tab2:checked + #tab1 + ul li:nth-of-type(2) label {
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 17px;
  background: #612e76;
}
#tab1:checked + ul li:first-of-type .tab-content,
#tab2:checked + #tab1 + ul li:nth-of-type(2) .tab-content {
  display: block;

#tab2:checked + #tab1 + ul + div + #hide-me {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Lato;
  color: #fff;
  background: #ddd;
}
h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px 0 100px 10px;
}
h1 span {
  font-size: 13px;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 4px;
}
.tabs {
  width: 650px;
  float: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  margin: 80px 0 0 10px;
  text-align: left;
}
.tabs li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display:none;
}
.tabs label {
  display: block;
  padding: 14px 21px;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: #8e44ad;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.tabs label:hover {
  background: #703688;
}
.tabs .tab-content {
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53px;
  left: 0;
  background: #612e76;
}
#tab1:checked + ul li:first-of-type label,
#tab2:checked + #tab1 + ul li:nth-of-type(2) label {
  top: 0;
  padding-top: 17px;
  background: #612e76;
}
#tab1:checked + ul li:first-of-type .tab-content,
#tab2:checked + #tab1 + ul li:nth-of-type(2) .tab-content {
  display: block;
}
p.link {
  clear: both;
  margin: 380px 0 0 15px;
}
p.link a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: #612e76;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
p.link a:hover {
  background-color: #522764;
}
#hide-me {
  margin-top: 250px;
  color: #000;
}
#tab2:checked + #tab1 + ul + div + #hide-me {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2" />
<input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab1" checked />
<ul class="tabs">
  <li>
    <label for="tab1">Description</label>
    <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <label for="tab2">Specification</label>
    <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
      <p>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia
        voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius
        modi tempora incidunt</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div style="clear:both;">
</div>

<div id="hide-me">
  HIDE ME HIDE ME HIDE ME
</div>
```

Comment: Yea works perfect, but I'm confused, what are I changed? Can you post here just that code which you added. Thank you

Comment: look at the input i moved it out of the container so you are able to target everything you need

Comment: thank you so much mate, you are master in front-end, this is so amazing :D
Can you send me our skype in chat, I will contact you sometimes, and I will pay you :D